# Как создать ToolBar во фрагменте на котлин?

Tags: android, kotlin

Как создавать тулбар в активити поняла, а как это сделать в самом фрагменте? (планирую разные тулбары для каждого из двух фрагментов, поэтому использование одного тулбара из активити не подходит)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавляете в xml фрагмента тулбар:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/bar_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.SubtitleText"
                app:title="@string/resume_string_14"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

из фрагмента получаете к нему доступ:

```
rootView.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar).apply {
            setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_home)

            setNavigationOnClickListener {
                requireActivity().finish()
            }
        }
```

можно добавить менюшку:

```
toolbar.apply {
            inflateMenu(R.menu.main_menu)
            menu.apply {
                findItem(R.id.write_message).isVisible = false
                findItem(R.id.filter).isVisible = false
            }
            title = getString(R.string.data_loading_title)
            subtitle = getString(R.string.data_loading_subtitle)
        }
```

из активности тоже можно юзать тулбары, но нужно будет отлавливать на каком вы фрагменте и скрывать/показывать элементы меню.